# Java Jsoup, как оставить &quot как &quot

Tags: java, jsoup

Мне нужно скачать html-документ, используя Jsoup, но при этом так, чтобы символы, которые написаны кодом остались как код (например, `&quot;`).

Вот простой пример такого кода:

```html
<p>\"Test message &quot;Hello&quot;\"</p>
```

Я хочу, чтобы Jsoup выводил то же самое, но выводит это:

```html
<p>"Test message "Hello""</p>
```

Мой код на Java:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<p>\"Test message &quot;Hello&quot;\"</p>");
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

Я пытался использовать это

```java
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

но не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему так:

```java
URL u = new URL(url);
c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
c.setUseCaches(false);
c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
c.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
c.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
c.connect();
int status = c.getResponseCode();
switch (status) {
    case 200:
    case 201:
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        br.close();
        resultJson = sb.toString();
        break;
```

В этом случае все символы, записанные кодом, остаются кодом. `Jsoup` же автоматически их декодирует.

Answer (score 0):

Экранировать `&` в  `&amp;`

```java
String htmlTag = "<p>\"Test message &quot;Hello&quot;\"</p>".replace("&", "&amp;");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlTag);
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

Comment: А можно код на Java, который это делает?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже бился над этой проблемой.
Решение оказалось простым

```
Connection.Response doc = Jsoup.connect(baseSite).ignoreHttpErrors(true).ignoreContentType(true).followRedirects(true).maxBodySize(0).timeout(0).execute();
String result = doc.body();
```